# My Button Functionality is Gone in Chrome but not Edge after using window.stop();

Tags: javascript, html

My Code works fine for the Edge Browser, but in the Chrome browser my buttons lose functionality. I've been looking for a solution (without changing the way I create the Modal) but have had no luck. Any help would be appreciated!

```
<div id= "myModal" class="Modal"> 
<div class="Modal-Content">
<button class="btn"id="yes"onclick="yes()" type=button>Yes!</button> 
<button class="btn"id="No"onclick="nah()" type=button>No</button>
</div>
</div>
<script>
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');
var x=document.cookie.indexOf("yay");
if(-1===x){
function yes(){document.cookie="yay";
window.location.reload(false);}
function nah(){window.location="https://www.google.com/"}  
modal.style.display = "block";
window.stop();
}
</script>
```

The window.stop function is helping my website speed a lot, so I really want to keep it.

Comment: You have a typo in your first button - and you need to surround the JS function listeners with quotes, `onclick="yes()"`.

Comment: The buttons are still not working, but other <p> links in Modal are, it's pretty strange

Answer (score 0):

The EventListener function worked in chrome & edge. Credits to @CertainPerformance for suggesting it!